# Store the last single-repeat into a register

Tags: vim

Sometimes I like to store my last single-repeat with `.` into a register to use it later with something like `@r`.

Any ideas how to solve this without repeating it using `qr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last executed command (what the `.` command repeats) is not accessible right now. Only the last inserted *text* is stored in the `".` register.

Therefore, you indeed have to actually manually repeat the change itself (recording the `.` application will store just that, and will *not* persist the actual repeated command) while recording a macro, or better recognize *before* the edit that you want to recall it, and trigger the macro recording before the first use.

Comment: Usually `".` would be sufficient. But on recording, I would not want to store `".P` but something like `i{content of register}^[`. Perhaps `:let @q='idummy^['` using `CTRL-R.`?

Answer (score 1):

What you repeat with `.` is transient: it is not stored anywhere in any useable form. This means that you are limited to repeating the latest editing action only.

One could probably record macros all the time (like [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4381) does) in order to be able to replay the nth previous action but that sounds like a wasteful endeavour.

But, well, `qr.q` is not very hard to type and can be mapped if that's really too much.

Comment: `qr.q` will record just that, you need to do `qr` {commands to recal} `q` actually.

Comment: Yes, I tried `qr.q` already. Calling `:registers` shows, that it stored just `.`.